# java-outer separate class access anonymous class

Tags: java, anonymous-class, anonymous-inner-class

Supposing I have the following classes

**Class0**

```
public abstract class Class0 {

public Class0(){}
    public void abmethod1(){
        System.out.println("Abstract method 1");
    }

    public void abmethod2(){
        System.out.println("Abstract method 2");
    }
}
```

**Class1**

```
public class Class1 {
    private List<Integer> aList;

    public Class1(){
        this.aList= new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Integer getElementAt(int i){
        return this.aList.get(i);
    }

    public int getSize(){
        return this.aList.size();
    }

    public void add(int num){
        this.aList.add(num);
    }
}
```

**Class2**

```
public class Class2 {
    private Class0 c0; 
    private Class3 c3;
    public Class2(){
        this.c0 = new Class0() {
            Class1 c1 = new Class1();

            @Override
            public void abmethod1(){
                System.out.println("Abstract method 1 called. Size is " + c1.getSize());
            }

            @Override
            public void abmethod2(){
                c1.add(1);
                c1.add(2);
                c1.add(3);
                System.out.println("Abstract method 2 called. Size is " + c1.getSize());
            }
       };
       this.c3 = new Class3();
       c3.methodc2(c0);
    }
}
```

**Class3**

```
public class Class3{
    public void methodc2(Class0 c0){
       c0.abmethod1();
       c0.abmethod2();
    }
}
```

**Class4**

```
public class Class4 {
    private Class2 c2;

    public Class4(){
        c2 = new Class2();
    }  
}
```

**Class5**

```
public class Class5 {
    private Class2 c2;

    public void method2(){
        this.c2 = new Class2();
    }
}
```

Then I run the main class

```
public class Class6 {
    public static void main(String[] afg){
        Class4 c4 = new Class4();
        Class5 c5 = new Class5();
        c5.method2();
    }
}
```

And I get the message

```
Abstract method 1 called. Size is 0
Abstract method 2 called. Size is 3
Abstract method 1 called. Size is 0
Abstract method 2 called. Size is 3
```

So I want to take the last size of my List (which is 3 here) every time I call the anonymous class inside Class3. How can I prevent it from creating a new instance of Class0, so as to take the output

```
Abstract method 1 called. Size is 0
Abstract method 2 called. Size is 3
Abstract method 1 called. Size is 3
Abstract method 2 called. Size is 6
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: It would *really* help if you'd indent your code more idiomatically... indent all your methods. (I've done it for you for now, but please pay more attention to formatting yourself in future.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how you want to indent..is it something wrong with spaces and styles...?

Comment: Compare how it looks now with how it looked before my edit. If you're using an IDE which does any indentation for you, I very much doubt that you have method declarations directly underneath the class declarations  that they're part of with no indentation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is that all instances of `Class2` would share the same instance of `Class0`, you can achieve it by making the `c0` member of `Class2` static. In that case, you'd initialize the `c0` variable in a static initialization block instead of in the constructor.

```
public class Class2 {
    private static Class0 c0; 
    private Class3 c3;
    static 
    {
         Class2.c0 = new Class0() {
            Class1 c1 = new Class1();

            @Override
            public void abmethod1(){
                System.out.println("Abstract method 1 called. Size is " + c1.getSize());
            }

            @Override
            public void abmethod2(){
                c1.add(1);
                c1.add(2);
                c1.add(3);
                System.out.println("Abstract method 2 called. Size is " + c1.getSize());
            }
        };
    }
    public Class2(){
       this.c3 = new Class3();
       c3.methodc2(c0);
    }
}
```

Whether all this makes sense is hard to say without knowing the purpose of your code.

Comment: well, it's more complex. I have a JTable and everytime I click a cell, I want to put cell coordinates in a List. After that, I press a button and color those cells with a color. But I can't color, because I get 0 in list size! :-)